# Null Coalesce Operator with a null last operand

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator

It works fine and doesn't cause problem

```
echo $formErrorBag[ 'email' ] ?? null
```

But is it an accepted practice? Never saw an example of this used with `null`.

Comment: But why? Can you provide an example of this?

Comment: just did so it was escaped.

Comment: Again, why would you do this? If `$formErrorBag['email']` is null this will already return null, you are just adding extra code that will make your application slower.

Comment: It avoids a php warning so it seems useful to me.

Comment: Won't it crash if $formErrorBag['email'] is not defined ?

Comment: @RobertBrax That's the whole point of the operator, to do an `isset` and return the value if it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's completely legal, and accepted. It's a pretty easy and elegant way to avoid raising an `E_NOTICE` if `$formErrorBag` doesn't have an `'email'` key.

Answer (score 1):

The null coalesce operator checks values with `isset()`, so this:

```
echo $formErrorBag['email'] ?? null;
```

Equals:

```
if(isset($formErrorBag['email'])){
  echo $formErrorBag['email'];
} else {
  echo null;
}
```

I really don't see the point in that as you are still executing a function doing literally nothing. If you are doing this to avoid raising an `E_NOTICE` you can simply turn it off with `error_reporting()` as doing your method kinda breaks the entire point of that.

It's there to warn you about a possible bug in your code, not finding techniques to suppress it.

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() ^ E_NOTICE); // turn notices off keep remaining flags intact.

echo $array['doesnotexist'];
echo $array['etc'];

error_reporting(error_reporting() | E_NOTICE); // turn it back on.
```